# TypeError: dojo._xdResourceLoaded(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget, cross-domain

I'm working on a project that requires that some custom Dojo widgets are loaded from another server.

I am wrapping everything with dojo._xdResourceLoaded(function() based on what was suggested at [Dojo - Issue loading widget cross-domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633973/dojo-issue-loading-widget-cross-domain)

I do get this error

TypeError: dojo._xdResourceLoaded(...) is not a function but my widget works. Not sure why it is throwing this error

We are using dojo 1.6.

```
dojo._xdResourceLoaded(function(){
 return {
 depends: [
 ["provide", "widgets.test"],
 ["require", "dijit._Widget"],
 ["require", "dijit._Templated"]
  ],
 defineResource: function(dojo) {
 ///////////////////////////////
  /// Begin standard declaration
 dojo.provide("widgets.test");
 dojo.require("dijit._Widget");
 dojo.require("dijit._Templated");
 dojo.declare("widgets.test", [dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated], {

// Our template - important!
templateString: dojo.cache("widgets.test", "templates/Widgettest.html"),
postCreate: function(){...
```

Answer (score 0):

The reply in the linked thread is not really correct. Your code, like all user code, should not call underscored (private) methods of the Dojo object. These methods are intended for use by Dojo code only.

If you are writing modules that load dependencies cross-domain using the legacy XD loader, you need to require all of your cross-domain dependencies and then wrap your code that uses those dependencies in `dojo.ready`:

```js
dojo.provide("widgets.test");
dojo.require("dijit._Widget");
dojo.require("dijit._Templated");
dojo.ready(function () {
    dojo.declare("widgets.test", [ dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated ], { /* … */ });
});
```

`dojo.ready` executes the callback once all the asynchronous dependencies are loaded.

Needless to say, AMD is much better than this, so upgrading to Dojo 1.7+ and using AMD modules would be the best solution as soon as you are capable.

Comment: I get this error uncaught exception: Could not load cross-domain resources:

Comment: Could you please show the HTML page that you are using to load dojo.js and your dojoConfig?

Comment: I have this on the html  <script type="text/javascript">
        
    dojo.registerModulePath('my', 'js/my');
</script> and  <script>dojo.require('my.widgets.test');
  dojo.require("dojo.io.script");dojo.addOnLoad(function(){/*---*/}